# Remove or add disabled to iCheck radio input

Tags: jquery, html, css, icheck

I have a radio input that uses iCheck jquery library. My radio input is disabled by default. I use jquery to enable the radio input using jquery prop(). Now my problem is when i enable the radio input, I'm not able to view the normal iCheck flat skin, instead I'm getting the disabled check view.

How do I fix this.

My HTML

```
<div class="radio">
 <label>
   <input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="iCheck" value="No" class="flat" disabled="disabled"> No
 </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="iCheck" id="iCheck" value="Yes" class="flat" disabled> Yes
  </label>
</div>
```

[Disable Radio Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj4KP.png)

[After enabling the input through jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEqEQ.png)

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PGSS.png)

Any help would be greately appreciated

UPDATE :

I have an edit button. On click edit button I can check the radio button.

```
<div class="rightpane">
    <button class="edit-btn">
        Edit
    </button>
</div>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function() {
        $('#iCheck').prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: Hi @theveil, you have to check css,

Comment: my css is working perfectly fine otherwise disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are enabling the radio input using jquery prop(). Technically, you are adding `checked` property as `true` at the same time **You need to add `disabled` property `false`** for your desired output.

Your Jquery be like

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function() {
   $('#iCheck').prop('disabled', false);
   $('#iCheck').prop('checked', true).iCheck('update');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that but didn't work out. any other way

Comment: Great!!!! It works like awsome. Only problem is that everytime I click the edit button it shows "Yes" option as checked even though "No" was checked before. Also, how to disable them back keeping the checked (if any) freezed. Anyhow thanks for your time and reply

Comment: I got them disabled back by $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function() {$('#iCheck').prop( "disabled", true ).iCheck('update');});

But how to keep the selected option when clicking edit button, and not reseting to "Yes" option everytime

Comment: OK. Finally I got everything working as per my requirement. I have removed the second line of @LulzAsh and simply put $('#iCheck').prop('disabled', false).iCheck('update'); . Thanks once again.

Comment: @theveil your code was correct but it not updating/reflecting the interface since icheck is external plugin it need to update by using `.iCheck('update');`